# Swing: most computationally-efficient way to blink particular cells in a table

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer

I need a way to draw attention to particular cells in a large JTable (20x16!), and I want to know what it would take for the text to blink, e.g. 900msec on and 100msec off.

(I'm familiar with the concept of a [`TableCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html))

Is there a way to do this just for the cells in question, without causing all the cells to redraw?

Comment: right then you have to read this very [interesting thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9607805/714968), please whole thread, answer by (@kleopatra) too, not only linked post by (@Hovercraft Full Of Eels :-)

Comment: `JTable`'s flyweight rendering is already fairly efficient, but see also [*Christmas Tree Applications*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/).

Comment: agreed! thank you -- please post as an answer

Comment: *"a large JTable (20x16!)"*  <DWS>OMG dude! I don't think anybody has ever tried to show a table with 320 cells or more in Java before.  Had you considered other languages better suited to this mammoth task?</DWS>  ROTFL..

Comment: Looking closer, `20 x 16 = 320`, but `20 x 16! = 502146957312000`. Please clarify.

Comment: how exactly are you achieving the blink? And where exactly is your _measured_ performance bottleneck?

Comment: @Andrew: I meant large from a user visibility standpoint.

Comment: @kleopatra: I haven't done it yet. I do Java programming only for a small part of my job, and can't afford to implement something only to find that it takes up 20 or 30% of the CPU and that I have to start over. I like to educate myself *before* starting on a programming task.

Comment: @trashgod: oh, come on, be reasonable. 502 trillion won't fit in an `int` (JTable/TableModel row + column indices are `int`) and that number of rows would have trouble navigating with scrollbars, let alone the issues caused by having to manage ultra-large amounts of data.

Comment: Fair enough; I may be a _little_ jaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required duty cycle (900 ms on, 100 ms off) and count (20 x 16) is well within the capability of `JTable` rendering, which uses the [*flyweight pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) for efficiency. On the rare occasion when profiling warrants, see the article [*Christmas Tree Applications*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/). See also this [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5799016/230513) with the `prepareRenderer()` approach.

Addendum: Also consider a `GridLayout` of `JLabel`, with each button having it's own instance of `javax.swing.Timer` to avoid synchronous blinking. The timers share a common thread.

Comment: arrgghh ... that old article again ... note that its bottom-line is: not much to gain whatever dirty short-cuts we might try :-)