# One large query or the couple of small for JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I'm trying to design some java program that show content of MySQL database in JTable. I dont know what is better: to load whole table to a Vector, and then put data for each cell of table from it. Or load each cell as separate query?

```
public class DBTableMode extends AbstractTableModel {   
...        
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = dao.getWholeData(); //my getter of whole data table
...
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        data.elementAt(rowIndex).elementAt(columnIndex);
}
...
```

OR

```
public class DBTableMode extends AbstractTableModel {
...
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        dao.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);

}
...
```

Actually I don't know the operational principle of JTable, if it loads data onScrolling then second variant is much better.
So, What is better in my case?

Comment: How big is your table likely to be?

Comment: It has no practical application, this is experimental problem, so I'm interested what is better when table has few hundreds and when it contain few thousands of records.

Comment: _I don't know the operational principle of JTable_ - not bad in itself, simply an incentive to learn: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to beat the convenience of `DefaultTableModel`, but [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) offers more flexibility over the internal data representation. I'd use something more recent and without the synchronization overhead of `Vector`. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) uses `Map<String, String>`. In any case, by encapsulating the choice inside your `TableModel`, you preserve the option of changing your mind as the program evolves.

Also consider `SwingWorker`, shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata), to build the model in the background.

`JTable` itself is just the view. Its rendering is [fairly efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624408/230513) already.

Comment: +1 @Yurgen maybe best of ways is spliting Sql ResultSet to a few separated ResultSets ---> MySQL implementing paginations in (Select .... LIMIT int, int),