# particular one table header color java swing

Tags: swing

I want to change the background color of particular table header. In my appliaction I have to set header color Red on the current month. [image]
My Code is here::

```
     jTable1.getTableHeader().
    setDefaultRenderer(
    new DefaultTableHeaderCellRenderer());



  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
          boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();

    if(column==1)
    tableHeader.setBackground(Color.red);


    return this;
  }
```

this make all the header color's red.
Please give me some suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The infamous color memory of DefaultTableCellRenderer :-) You have to

- set the background color always: that is for both normal and highlighted state
- do so *before* calling super

something like:

```
  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
        int column) {
      if (myHighlightCondition) {
          setBackground(Color.RED);
      } else {
          setBackground(null);
      }
     super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
           row, column);
     return this;
  }
```

For more details (and why that's needed) see a [How do I correctly use custom renderers to paint specific cells in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607670/how-do-i-correctly-use-customer-renderers-to-paint-specific-cells-in-a-jtable/9617446#9617446)

Comment: +1 to this answer and the linked answer. Now that is something worth remembering to avoid loosing heaps of time the next time I am working with tables