# How to use Renderer for TableHeader

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

Even I read and test answers by @kleopatra

- [How do I correctly use customer renderers to paint specific cells in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617446/714968)
- [particular one table header color java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9839059/714968)
- about `super.getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` must be last code line before returns, I'm not able to write correct Renderer by those suggestion, for me works only this way
- `JLabel` is added for Borders, HorizontalAlignment and Foreground, especially Background caused me a few non_senses by using Component instead of `JLabel`, (not important here somehow)

[image]

[image]

[image]

from [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SelectedTableHeader {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Demo");
    private JTableHeader header;
    private Object selectedColumn = null;
    private String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Float", "Double", "Locale & Double", "Boolean"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"aaa", new Integer(12), new Float(12.15), new Double(100.05), new Double(12.05), true},
        {"bbb", new Integer(5), new Float(7.154), new Double(6.1555), new Double(417.55), false},
        {"CCC", new Integer(92), new Float(0.1135), new Double(3.1455), new Double(11.05), true},
        {"ddd", new Integer(12), new Float(31.15), new Double(10.05), new Double(23.05), true},
        {"eee", new Integer(5), new Float(5.154), new Double(16.1555), new Double(17.55), false},
        {"fff", new Integer(92), new Float(4.1135), new Double(31.1455), new Double(3.05), true}};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public SelectedTableHeader() {
        header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JTableHeader h = (JTableHeader) e.getSource();
                int i = h.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                Object o = h.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getHeaderValue();
                if (i < 0) {
                    selectedColumn = null;
                    return;
                }
                selectedColumn = o;
                h.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        final TableCellRenderer hr = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        header.setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

            private JLabel lbl;

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                if (selectedColumn == value) {
                    lbl = (JLabel) hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, true, true, row, column);
                    lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(lbl.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 1)));
                    lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                } else {
                    lbl = (JLabel) hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, row, column);
                    lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(lbl.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0)));
                    lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                }
                if (column == 0) {
                    lbl.setForeground(Color.red);
                } else {
                    lbl.setForeground(header.getForeground());
                }
                /*return (value == selectedColumn) ? hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, true, true, row, column) : hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, false, false, row, column);*/
                return lbl;
            }
        });
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SelectedTableHeader selectedTableHeader = new SelectedTableHeader();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are having? The SSCCE works fine for me.

Comment: @Jakub Zaverka maybe there isn't issue with Render, true is I have issues with ArraysXxxException by implements Renderer by (@kleopatra)

Comment: EDIT removed use_less RowSorter

Comment: What do you mean, ArraysXxxException? Like ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: @mKorbel: Works for me, too. I think kleopatra's answer refers to  an implementation detail in `DefaultTableCellRenderer`; in contrast, your custom implementation of `TableCellRenderer` works around the problem in a different way.

Comment: @trashgod agreed, you are right, heavens, without any success,

Comment: @mKorbel: If you extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` in order to apply kleopatra's approach, could you do something like [`applyUI()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513) the get the header decorations?

Comment: you are getting array out of bounds acception while adding or deleting rows.. I am asking because i have also faced same problem...

Comment: hmm ... what's the problem? And why that funny way of configuring the default header (as your rendering component _is_ the default)

Comment: @kleopatra there are some differencies betweens methods accesible for (J)Component and JLabel, maybe in this time JLabel can't implements something that invoked me .....,

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, it's better to get the `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer` when you overwrite any `JTable` `Renderer`. So, instead of messing with the `JLabel` from the `Renderer` directly, you grab the `Renderer` with `super()`. So, your code should look like this:

```
header.setDefaultRenderer(new DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer() {


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer rendererComponent = (DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (selectedColumn == value) {
            rendererComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(rendererComponent.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 1)));
            rendererComponent.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        } else {
            rendererComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(rendererComponent.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0)));
            rendererComponent.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        }
        if (column == 0) {
            rendererComponent.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            rendererComponent.setForeground(header.getForeground());
        }

        return rendererComponent;
    }
});
```

To try and answer your questions directly:

**Question 1:**

Q: How do I correctly use customer renderers to paint specific cells in a JTable?

A: Your current code is setting a `Renderer` on the `JTableHeader`. To add a Renderer on your table cells would be similar code to what's above, only you'd set it through the Column model:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        // Set your code to render your component.

        return renderer;
    }

});
```

Note about this: `JTables` are column-based, which means that all the data in a certain column must be the same type (your SSCCE follows this convention). My favorite thing to do is to provide a custom `Renderer` for each type. For example, whenever I have a `Date` column, I use this renderer:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class DateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    String pattern;
    public DateCellRenderer(String pattern){
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value != null && value instanceof LocalDate) {
            renderer.setText(((LocalDate)value).toString(pattern));
        } else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only supported Object type is LocalDate.");

        return renderer;
    }
}
```

And I call this code with something similar:

```
table.getColumn("Date Entered").setCellRenderer(new DateCellRenderer("MMM dd, yyyy"));
```

**Question 2:**

Q: particular one table header color java swing

A: Umm.. Your SSCCE seems to have it figured out.

**Question 3:**

Q: about super.getTableCellRendererComponent(...) must be last code line before returns, I'm not able to write correct Renderer by those suggestion, for me works only this way

A: I'm not sure what you mean "must be last code line before returns." That is not the case, proven by the code snip I gave above

**Question 4:**

Q: JLabel is added for Borders, HorizontalAlignment and Foreground, especially Background caused me a few non_senses by using Component instead of JLabel, (not important here somehow)

A: Ok... the `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer` is sufficient for all of those, borders, alignment, foreground and background.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me in the past and I was convinced it had to do with the Cell Renderer, but the `ArraysXxxException` kind of Exceptions hunted me because I had forgotten to **unselect and stop editing** the cell before adding/removing rows. You should try `clearSelection()` and `table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();` on your `JTable` before remove/add and see if that solves your problem.

First, of course, make sure it is editing:

```
if (table.isEditing()) {
    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
}
```