# Spacing JTable header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I know spacing `JTable` cells are pretty straight forward as shown below;

```
int gapWidth = 10;
int gapHeight = 5;
table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(gapWidth, gapHeight));
```

Spacing like this doesn't seems to affect the tables header. Is there a way to space the header with the same dimension?

Comment: it's not clear what exactly you are after (_alignment of header and the actual row cell values looks slighly off_ - not only slightly, the header is centered :-) - best to show an SSCCE to demonstrate the issue (as @mKorbel already suggested)

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing as @mKorbel, the only difference in my code is, I have sized up two of my columns.

Comment: but in his example there is no text (that's what you are after?) alignment (between header/cell) at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way could be to set [EmptyBorders to the JTableHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9851253/714968) inside the `TableCellRenderer`

> The code above does my spacing, but the alignment of header and the actual row cell values looks slighly off - as a result of spacing only placed on cells but not the header.

I added a SSCCE (3mins 27seconds inc. uploading here)

[image][image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class IntercellSpacingTableHeader {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Demo");
    private String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Float", "Double"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"aaa", new Integer(12), new Float(12.15), new Double(100.05)},
        {"bbb", new Integer(5), new Float(7.154), new Double(6.1555)},
        {"CCC", new Integer(92), new Float(0.1135), new Double(3.1455)},
        {"ddd", new Integer(12), new Float(31.15), new Double(10.05)},
        {"eee", new Integer(5), new Float(5.154), new Double(16.1555)},
        {"fff", new Integer(92), new Float(4.1135), new Double(31.1455)}};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public IntercellSpacingTableHeader() {
        int gapWidth = 10;
        int gapHeight = 5;
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(gapWidth, gapHeight));
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new IntercellSpacingTableHeader();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try that, but the requirement here do not accept the approach if you see what I mean.

Comment: @Bitmap I havent't any issue with that, but maybe there is/are another issue(s), you can use linked code for creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), maybe someone ....

Comment: The code above does my spacing, but the alignment of header and the actual row cell values looks slighly off - as a result of spacing only placed on cells but not the header.

Comment: I have set gapWidth to 5 and seems to align with cell data.