# Change the color of a row in a jTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a jTable as following :

[image]

I want when the value in the `Quantité` is less than  the value in the `Min seuil de suantité`, to change the color of the row to pink.

In the load of the program all works fine, but when I do some event like click on the table, the color of all the rows is changed even if the the value of the `Quantité` is not less than  the value of the `Min seuil de quantité` :

[image]

this is my cell rendering :

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

        int selectedRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
        if (table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 3) != null && table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 4) != null) {
            int quantite = Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 3).toString());
            int minQuantite = Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 4).toString());
            if (quantite < minQuantite) {
                if (isSelected) {
                    cell.setBackground(new Color(255, 138, 239));
                } else {
                    cell.setBackground(new Color(252, 189, 252));
                }
            }
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

and this is the code which allows me to affect the cell rendering to my table :

```
private void cellRendering(){
        for (int i = 0; i < masterTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            tcol = masterTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) is a rubber stamp that *remembers* what ink was applied last. Be sure to set the desired color each time the renderer is invoked. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617446/230513).

Comment: @user2417302 not wrong, again the same issue, really time to use prepareRenderer, do not parse whatever stored in XxxTableModel, put there Double, Integer, whatever  from  Number instance, most of issue will be resolved by posting an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for XxxTableModel

Comment: @user2417302 for rest of (any) issues to [see my post about](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16814512/714968), I'm sure that I saw very similair question on another Java Forum or am wrong