# Changing jtable cell color after jitem click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am new on Java Swing. I have jtable which in column 2, when doing a right click on a cell a jpopmenu shows with two options(in progress / solved) and I want to modify cell color to green when clicking option "Solved". I know that I need a cell Renderer. How to put it?

There's my source code:

```
public class logaff {

static File font_file = new File("font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.ttf");
static JPopupMenu pm;
static JMenuItem one = new JMenuItem();
static JMenuItem two = new JMenuItem();
static JTable table;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException,
        IOException {
    Font fontt = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, font_file);
    Font sizedFont = fontt.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 15);
    JPanel logaffich = new JPanel();
    logaffich.setBackground(Color.black);
    logaffich.setLayout(null);

    JPanel tableau = new JPanel();
    tableau.setLocation(5, 15);
    tableau.setSize(790, 520);
    tableau.setBackground(Color.white);

    JButton a = new JButton("fg");
    String[] columnNames = { "ID", "Description", "Status", "Cam",
            "Elapsed Time" };
    String[][] data = new String[10][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            data[i][j] = "Table " + i + ", " + j;

        }
    }

    int[] columnsWidth = { 158, 450, 60, 40, 80 };

    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    int k = 0;
    for (int width : columnsWidth) {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(k++);
        column.setMinWidth(width);
        column.setMaxWidth(width);
        column.setPreferredWidth(width);
        table.setRowHeight(55);
    }

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    tableau.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tableau.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pm = new JPopupMenu();
    pm.add(one);
    pm.add(two);

    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            try {
                showPopup(me);
            } catch (FontFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    logaffich.add(tableau);
    TitledBorder title1;

    title1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "New Log Alert",
            TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.TOP, sizedFont, Color.white);
    logaffich.setBorder(title1);

    // panel pour le formulaire
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(logaffich);
    // Create and set up the content pane.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(808, 565);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private static void showPopup(MouseEvent me) throws FontFormatException,
        IOException {
    // is this event a popup trigger?
    if (pm.isPopupTrigger(me)) {
        Point p = me.getPoint();
        final int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
        final int col = table.columnAtPoint(p);
        // if we've clicked on a row in the second column
        if (row != -1 && col == 1) {
            File font_file = new File("font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.ttf");

            Font fontt = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,font_file);
            Font sizedFont = fontt.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 17);
            final ImageIcon progress = new ImageIcon("images/progress.png");
            one.setIcon(progress);
            one.setFont(sizedFont);
            final ImageIcon ok = new ImageIcon("images/ok.png");
            two.setIcon(ok);
            two.setFont(sizedFont);

            one.setText("In progress " + row + ".");
            two.setText("Solved " + row + ".");
            pm.show(table, p.x, p.y);

        }
        one.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                System.out.println("sfsdf" + row);

            }

        });
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read docs about [Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). For proper use of it.

Next code add custom cell renderer to your column:

```
 TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
 column.setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
```

Example code for `getRenderer` method:

```
private static TableCellRenderer getRenderer() {
return new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
            boolean solved = false;
            if (value.toString().endsWith("Solved")) {
                solved = true;
                value = value.toString().replace("Solved", "");
            }
            Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (solved) {
                tableCellRendererComponent.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                tableCellRendererComponent.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            return tableCellRendererComponent;
    }
};
}
```

That method returns [DefaultTableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html). Here in `if-else` statement you determine background for cell.

EDIT:
1) Changed `getRenderer` method.

2)create your popUp in next way:

```
 pm = new JPopupMenu();
pm.add(one);
pm.add(two);
one.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        if(row != -1)
        System.out.println("sfsdf" + row);

    }

});

two.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        if(row != -1){
            Object valueAt = table.getValueAt(row,1);
            table.setValueAt(valueAt+"Solved", row,1);
            ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    }

});
```

because you add Listeners every time you call `showPopup` method instead of that you must to add it only once as in my example.
`row` field I set as static field.

3) your method showPopup changed:

```
private static void showPopup(MouseEvent me) throws FontFormatException,
    IOException {

// is this event a popup trigger?
if (pm.isPopupTrigger(me)) {
    Point p = me.getPoint();
    row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
    final int col = table.columnAtPoint(p);
    // if we've clicked on a row in the second column
    if (row != -1 && col == 1) {
        final ImageIcon progress = new ImageIcon("images/progress.png");
        one.setIcon(progress);
        final ImageIcon ok = new ImageIcon("images/ok.png");
        two.setIcon(ok);

        one.setText("In progress " + row + ".");
        two.setText("Solved " + row + ".");
        pm.show(table, p.x, p.y);

    } 

}
}
```

4) create your table next way `table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));`

If you change your code as I recomended, when you push **Solved** in popUp then cell will be with green background.

Comment: I want to modify cell color to green when clicking option "Solved". == [TableCellRenderer and how to refresh Cell background without using JTable.repaint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814512/tablecellrenderer-and-how-to-refresh-cell-background-without-using-jtable-repain)

Comment: Thank you very much it adds "solved" on the cell beut the color is not working

Comment: I recommend to use wrapper(decorator) objects for rows, in this case it will be easier to manage data.

Comment: Excuse me another problem is that when i change setbackground by setforeground it makes alla columns green not only the text because it's all the row which will be in green not the background

Comment: For Foreground use this `if (solved) { tableCellRendererComponent.setForeground(Color.GREEN);} else {    tableCellRendererComponent.setForeground(table.getForeground());}`

Comment: Ok one more question, i want all the row to be in green except column one (0)

Comment: You need renderers for all columns