# Giving an object a method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, instantiation

Having trouble finding information on the thing I'm after as I'm not sure what the process is called. As an example, check out the code below.

When making a GUI, the following is used (copy/paste from internet):

```
regionSelectionTable = new JTable()
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col)
    {
        //Do some stuff
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        JComponent jcomp = (JComponent)comp;

        if (comp == jcomp) 
        {
            jcomp.setToolTipText((String)getValueAt(row, col));
        }

        return comp;
    };
};
```

I'm not so interested in what happens inside the prepareRenderer() method; but rather, **is the JTable object being given a method in the above code?** 
If true:

- what is this process called?
- why isn't the method being passed as an argument to the constructor
  or via a setter method?

If this is not what is happening, please explain what is happening and what this process is called.

Comment: No, not really, you are creating what is known as an [Anonymous Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), which, in this case, is overriding the `prepareRenderer` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really, you are creating what is known as an [Anonymous Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), which, in this case, is overriding the `prepareRenderer` method.

Technically, you could add new methods to the class, but unless you are calling them internally, you won't be able to access them externally, as from the outside, it's just a `JTable`

Comment: `you won't be able to access them externally, as from the outside, it's just a JTable` - [reason for my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16814512/714968), its feature, but with buggy history

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding an existing method by creating a nameless class that extends JTable.