# Highlight cell when row is selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cellrenderer

The problem I am having is that when I select a row, the cell with a custom cell renderer doesn't highlight that cell but does the other cells.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table,
    Object value,
    boolean isSelected,
    boolean hasFocus,
    int row,
    int column)
{
    setFont(ApplicationStyles.TABLE_FONT);

    if (value != null)
    {
        BigDecimal decimalValue = toBigDecimal(value);
        decimalValue =
            decimalValue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$##,##0.00");
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        String formattedValue = formatter.format(value);
        setText(formattedValue);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to format data is to override the `setValue(...)` method of the default renderer as demonstrated in the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). Then you don't have to worry about the highlighting.

Or maybe easier is to use the [Table Format Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) then all you need to provide is the `Format` to be used by the renderer.

Answer (score 4):

You [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) should check `isSelected` and condition the `Component`  colors accordingly. In outline,

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
    boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
    …
    if (isSelected) {
        setForeground(getSelectionForeground());
        setBackground(getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        setForeground(getForeground());
        setBackground(getBackground());
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9607670/230513) discussing `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.

Comment: Also, if the op is using DefaultTableCellRenderer, just call the super method, but since the op hasn't provided this information, this is the best solution

Comment: I am not using the DefaultTableCellRenderer but implementing TableCellRenderer

Comment: @MadProgrammer is correct; I cited the related  Q&A as a guide to avoiding this [pitfall](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617446/230513); see also this related currency [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).