# Highlight found data in JTable row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, filtering, tablerowsorter

I want to search data from `JTable` when data found then I want to highlight table row. This code is work properly search record but I don't know what I do for highlight the row.

```
  String target = jTextField1.getText();
    for(int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++)
    for(int col = 0; col < jTable1.getColumnCount(); col++)
        {
    String next = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(row, col);
        if(next.equals(target))
        {
            System.out.println("found");// here what change for highlight row.
        }
        }
```

Comment: Already answered - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520548/is-there-anyway-i-can-highlight-a-row-in-jtable

Comment: *"i want to search data from jtable.."*  See [`JTable`: Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your idea of "highlighting"

You could use [`JTable#addRowSelection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#addRowSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29) to highlight a row using the default selection

Or, you could setup your cell renders to apply additional highlighting support via an additional lookup to determine if the cell/row should be highlighted

Or, you could use the inbuilt filtering capabilities of the `JTable` to filter out unwanted content

See [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Or, you could use the highlighting support from the SwingLabs, SwingX librRies

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve that with a custom JLabel and TableCellRenderer.
Following example does the highlighting on the found (filtered) rows in JTable. The rows are filtered via RowFilter:
http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/swing/jtable-row-filter-highlighting/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(e.getSource()==field){
            int z;
            for(z = 0;z<table.getRowCount();z++){
                if(Integer.parseInt(field.getText()) == Integer.parseInt((String)table.getValueAt(z, 1))){
                    break;
                     }
            }
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(z, z);


        }
```

i had the same problem and this was how i went about it.